# Added reputation doesn't seem to be correct

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I have been assigned some reputation points for the this question on Stack Overflow : 
[what happened if SESSION is already created and now i'm going to create SESSION of same name in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153703/what-happened-if-session-is-already-created-and-now-im-going-to-create-session/21153704#21153704)

I do not understand. I have not asked the question. My answer is not upvoted. Why are the reputation points added?

Comment: [Your answer is both upvoted and down voted.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NaImn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one upvote and a downvote on that answer:

> [image]

You can see actual vote counts one you cross [1000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

So, you earned 10 - 2 = 8 reputation points, as you can see in the [reputation tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115784/akanksha?tab=reputation):

[image]

Comment: okay, as the final number is 0 I couldn't figure that out. Thanks :)